# get 404 when trying to access files directly

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi project with a folder called "images".

I want to access the images directly but I keep getting 404 with message "No type was found that matches the controller named 'images'."

I did the same thing on MVC project and it always worked well, I don't know why in WebApi I can't access files.

I'm sure the file is there, I see it in the directory.

Example request: GET http://localhost:49873/images/20180704003126241.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under a default configuration WebAPI won't serve static files for you. You need to either

- Set up a controller on the WebAPI endpoint that will get the files and return a `FileResult`
- Configure static file handling middleware

9 times out of 10 you'll want the second one. Note that the *default* configuration for Microsoft's static file middleware is to serve static content out of `wwwroot` so you'll probably need to put your images folder there.

Comment: I installed Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles and moved the images folder in wwwroot. Now it works.

Comment: @DanieleLewis Glad to hear it!